# Creating multiple instances in libgdx Box2d

Tags: java, object, libgdx, box2d, instances

I create an object in [box2d](/questions/tagged/box2d), lets say a square and I want to make many copies of square with different coordinates so I can call it with

```
Square square = new Square(int x, int y)
```

Inside square I created a method that changes the square color.
What I'm trying to do is create multiple instances of square

```
square = new Square(2, 4);
square = new Square(9, 7);
.
.
.
```

and when I call `square.changeColor()` I want all of them to change, what would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Color` in the square class static.

**What are static variables?**

A simplified explanation of it would be that when you make a change in an Object(`Square`) of a particular static variable(`Color`). It will change across all instances of the object (`Square`).

**More information:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a static variable for color, that way there will be one across all instances.

Comment: I have the method 
public static void stop() {
  square.setGravityScale(0f);
  square.setLinearVelocity(Vars.scrollSpeed / PPM, 0);
 }

square is a box2d object so it moves from right to left, when I call the methos stop it works no problems. 
when I create many squares

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
Square square = new Square();
}
this creates 5 squares with the same name (all called "square")
when I call square.stop() only the last one created stops, how can I make that all of them execute the stop method?

Comment: Or should I create a list of objects and call the method on each one of them

Comment: You can make the variable representing the speed static as well, but this will mean that all your squares constantly move the same speed. You could also create a new static variable, boolean stop, and have the squares only move if stop is false, then change it to try in your method.